# Cannot delete Google OAuth client ID

Tags: credentials, google-oauth, clientid

I have 15 entries on my OAuth 2.0 client IDs list on Google Cloud Platform console, associated with my application.

I need only one, and it does have a proper name, but 14 others have name "New Actions on Google App".

I was requested to delete unneeded client IDs by a OAuth2 approval team.

But, when I am attempting to delete them, I am getting an error:

Error

You do not have permission to perform this action.

Tracking Number: c602996690

There is a link to Send Feedback.  I did send feedback, but there is no reply.

I do not know where these entries came from.  I am requested to delete them to get approved.  I need to be go through the approval, because I am requesting certain sensitive content.  Unfortunately, I cannot delete those entries, and I do not see any ways to contact Google.

Any suggestions, please?  Or, pointers who I should contact?

Thanks
Artchil Gogava